# Permission dennied when getting authed_session

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-tasks

I'm encountering a 'permission denied' error while attempting to execute python / get_function_url as per the instructions provided in the following URL:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/task-functions?hl=ja&gen=2nd

I'm seeking guidance on how to resolve this issue. Can anyone provide assistance or insights into why this error is occurring and how to fix it?

the error is like below.

```
{
  "textPayload": "[2023-10-23 13:34:51,936][ERROR] Function failed to deploy: {'error': {'code': 403, 'message': \"Permission 'cloudfunctions.functions.get' denied on 'projects/xxxxxx/locations/asia-northeast1/functions/xxxxxx'\", 'status': 'PERMISSION_DENIED'}}",
  "insertId": "6536767b000e4c64b7d00166",
  "resource": {
    "type": "cloud_run_revision",
    "labels": {
      "location": "asia-northeast1",
      "revision_name": "xxxxxx-00005-vem",
      "project_id": "project_id",
      "service_name": "name",
      "configuration_name": "name"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2023-10-23T13:34:51.937060Z",
  "labels": {
    "instanceId": "0037d6d5d376f82f755b63a9e71e623e000cbf5347fae7dc461dd197193ce4c0d6d076565d0710b9cc5030eca98e527a60b36eba4dde5111a7f4ac1f081a40769ec2",
    "goog-managed-by": "cloudfunctions"
  },
  "logName": "projects/xxxxxx/logs/run.googleapis.com%2Fstderr",
  "receiveTimestamp": "2023-10-23T13:34:52.095133254Z"
}
```

Thank you.